# Unable to parse JSON in Freemarker 2.3.21

Tags: freemarker

I have a valid json. Which I want to assign to a variable to be used in the page. But FTL is throwing error suggesting "the string is evaluated to null or missing".

I was able to do the same operation in 2.1.X versions smoothly.

What I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You should post some code and JSON that shows the problem, otherwise it's just guesswork.

Comment: And the actual error message too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is was zeroed down to null values. In 2.3.x, we cannot use null as a value to json properties. Instead I had to replace it with empty string. Also, comparison of numeric value with string is no more allowed.

Fixed these issues and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you try to migrate from FreeMarker 2.1.x to 2.3.x, even if you haven't realized that that assumes some extra migration work. Consider early 2.x.x FreeMarker versions, i.e. those before 2.3.0 (released in 2004, 11 years ago) as still boiling and fragile when it comes to backward compatibility. (This is also apparent from the version history and version policy statement on the download page.)

The main migration issue used to be that FreeMarker has become stricter over time when it comes to nulls and missing variables. Though that change was already done 2.1.0, but maybe some rough edges on that department was polished later... (Or, are you migration from 2.01 instead? That meant to be 2.0.1, but back in the dark ages the authors managed to mess it up somehow...)

Also note that there's a configuration setting, `classic_compatible`. It was mainly used to help migration from 1.x to the stricter later versions. So basically it makes FreeMarker being more lenient. Maybe it was turned on earlier and now somehow was turned off?